# Refresh token on Google OAuth2 PHP library

Tags: php, google-oauth

I implemented Google OAuth2 for user login on my website.
It works but after 1 hour token expires and login fails.
I read on the web that I need to get the Refresh Token (for Facebook Login I used a *Long Lived Token*), but code I tried doesn't work.
Here the code:

```php
//LOGIN CALLBACK FROM GOOGLE
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName(SITE_TITLE);
$gClient->setClientId(get_option('google_api_id')->value);
$gClient->setClientSecret(get_option('google_api_secret')->value);
$gClient->addScope('profile');
$gClient->addScope('email');
$gClient->setRedirectUri(SITE_URL."/login/google/google-callback.php");

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $gClient->setAccessType('offline');
    $token = $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $gClient->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
    $_SESSION['google_access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
}

if($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
    // Get user profile data from google
    $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
    $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
}

...
```

This first snippet works fine.

In this second snipped, when user change page, I verify if login is still active:

```php
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName(SITE_TITLE);
$gClient->setClientId(get_option('google_api_id')->value);
$gClient->setClientSecret(get_option('google_api_secret')->value);
$gClient->addScope('profile');
$gClient->addScope('email');
$gClient->setAccessType('offline');
$gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['google_access_token']);
if($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
  if ($gClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($gClient->getRefreshToken());
  }
  $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
  $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
  ...
}
```

This second snipped doesn't work, because method `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($gClient->getRefreshToken())` fails because `$gClient->getRefreshToken()` is NULL.

I debugged the callback and I saw that `$token = $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode` returns an array without "refresh_token" field.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Bye